# I recently started synthetic division

Tags: polynomials

When the polynomial $3x^3+ax^2+bx-9$ is divided by $x-2$, the remainder is $-5$. When it is divided by $x+1$, the remainder is $-16$. What are the values of $a$, and $b$.

Comment: Hint: When dividing by $x-c$, then substituting $x=c$ in the polynomial results in the remainder...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck and in what context you have encountered the problem
, i.e edit your post with this information. 
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Well I tried the synthetic division formula which did not help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$P(x)=(3x^3+ax^2+bx-9)=q(x)(x-2)-5\Rightarrow P(2)=24+4a+2b-9=-5$$
On the other hand:
$$P(x)=(3x^3+ax^2+bx-9)=p(x)(x+1)-16\Rightarrow P(-1)=-3+a-b-9=-16$$
thus, you have to solve the $2\times 2$ liner system
$$
2a+b=-20 \\
a-b=-4
$$